# Why does finally execute although we have continue in except block which transfers the control to the top of the while?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch-finally

Here is the code

```
while True:
   try: 
     age = int(input("Enter your age"))
   except ValueError:
     print("Enter the age in integer")
     continue
   except ZeroDivisionError:  #when trying to divide the age for an age groups
     print("Age cannot be zero")
     continue
   else:
     print("thank you!!")
     break
   finally:
     print("ok! I am finally done")
```

In the input, for age I give a string (eg: wefervrsvr) so it must go through the `ValueError` in the except block which has `print` function and then `continue` statement that makes the control of the program to the top in the loop so it asks for input again from us, but the thing I don't understand here is that why does finally executes before the control jumps to try block at the top as I see in the output.

Comment: That's the point of `finally`, it gets executed pretty much no matter what. You could even have a `return` statement in the `try` or `except`, `finally` will still be executed.

Comment: ya but why executes before continue's control jumps to try block again, why not after that try block executes successfully and then else block break out of the infinite loop and finally executes anyhow before breaking out.

Comment: Upon the `continue` statement, python recognizes, that you'll going to leave the `try` segment (jump to the beginning of the `while` loop) and eventually execute the `finally` block

Comment: @Maestro because it has to get executed **before**  the entire `try-except-finally` exits which it does when it jumps to the next loop iteration.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I got it thanks a lot

Comment: @SimonFink got it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`python docs`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally):

> When a return, break or continue statement is executed in the try suite of a try...finally statement, the finally clause is also executed ‘on the way out'.

'on the way out' basically means, if a `continue` statement is executed inside of an exception clause, the code in the `finally` clause will be executed and then the loop will continue on to the next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The `finally` block exists to guarantee you can execute some code, regardless of what happens in the `try` block. The `continue` keyword will not circumvent it and even an unhandled exception will not circumvent it.

If you removed that catch of the `ValueError`, for example, you will still hit the finally block:

```
try:
    raise ValueError("unhandled exception type");
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("problems.")
finally:
    print("will print, even in the face of an unhandled exception")
```

Answer (score 1):

A decent answer for this

```
import time;
while True:
    try:
        print("waiting for 10 seconds...\n")
        continue
        print("never show this")
    finally:
        print("Finally starts executing\n");
        time.sleep(10)
        print("\nFinally ends executing control jumps to start of the loop");
```